# Error trying to list all objects in django databse

Tags: python, django, database, typeerror

I am trying to list all out all objects in terminal.

This is the model for my object:

```
from django.db import models

class Game(models.Model):
    gameId = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    awayId = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    awayCity = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    awayName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    awayAbr = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    homeId = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    homeCity = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    homeName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    homeAbr = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    isUnplayed = models.BooleanField()
    isInProgress = models.BooleanField()
    isCompleted = models.BooleanField()
    awayScore = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    homeScore = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.gameId)
```

I then try and run this in terminal:

```
Game.objects.all()
```

To which i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Dean/Documents/codingProjects/Python/isItClose/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 229, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "/Users/Dean/Documents/codingProjects/Python/isItClose/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 589, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

I have already created some data in terminal like this:

```
>>>a = Game(gameId="1",date="2016-05-01",time="1:10PM",awayId="136",awayCity="San Fran",awayName="Giants",awayAbr="SF",homeId="127",homeCity="New york",homeName="Yankees",homeAbr="NYY",isUnplayed=False,isInProgress=False,isCompleted=True,awayScore="4",homeScore="6")

>>> a.Save()
```

Thanks for any advice!!

Comment: Is there any more to the traceback that you haven't shown? If you've changed the `__str__` method since you've opened the shell, then save your file and restart the shell.

Comment: i just added the rest of the error. apologies. but you were right!! Thanks so much, i closed the shell and restarted it and it was all good!! thanks so much